# If mankind is a bridge then why would the anti-christ need to rewill history prior to themselves?

Tags: nietzsche, philosophy-of-history

If mankind is a bridge then why would the anti-christ need to rewill history prior to themselves? Has anyone discussed that issue?

> What is great in man is that he is a bridge and not a goal: what is
>   lovable in man is that he is an over-going and a down-going.

From part 4 of Zarathustra's [prologue](http://praxeology.net/zara.htm).

Comment: Because to maintain the tautness of the tightrope, you have to apply tension at both ends; at least we can maybe venture this: that understanding the ape and its abilities is quite important to understanding the potential abilities of humanity, and so perhaps especially to foreseeing what comes after humanity

Comment: @JosephWeissman maybe, but then man is still the measure

Comment: Man may be a dynamic measure of the compression of the tightrope between ape and post-human. It seems like we not far here from N's idea that our highest notions (beauty, goodness) still have an "apish" quality... I can try to put some of this into an answer but sharpening the question a bit here would help

Comment: @JosephWeissman how would you sharpen it? seems like it works ok, as it is ?